# ActionController::TestCase mock PayPal purchase

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, paypal, functional-testing, activemerchant

Is there a way to mock the purchase of PaypalExpressGateway

I have used two actions for PayPal payment processing,
first action take the user to paypal sandbox login and will redirect back to my application for payment confirmation

But the `PAYPAL_GATEWAY.purchase` method is not succeeding and returns with an error message `Payment has not been authorized by the user.`

Well I guess this is due to the skipped step for authorizing purchase by user

**Is there a way I could just fake or mock PayPal to accept the transaction ?**

My `ActionController::TestCase` to test the actions `products#initiate_payment` `products#confirm_payment` call these actions as

```
post :initiate_payment, initiate_payment_action_params(@product)
get :confirm_payment, confirm_action_params(@product, product_purchased, paypal_token)
```

And to setup the paypal callback response then redirect to paypal login

```
@setup_response = PAYPAL_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(amount, ip: request.remote_ip,
      items: [{name: @product.name, quantity: 1, description: @product.description, amount: amount}],
      currency: 'USD',
      return_url: url_for(action: 'confirm_payment',
                                 product_purchased: @product_purchased.id,                                   
                                 only_path: false),    
      cancel_return_url: url_for(action: 'index',
                                 product_purchased: @product_purchased.id,
                                 only_path: false))

redirect_to PAYPAL_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(@setup_response.token)
```

I have handled the purchase transaction in my `products#confirm_payment` action
I have mocked the params for confirm_payment as

```
{"product_purchased"=>"10", "token"=>"EC-91J25480XA799581U", "PayerID"=>"4QBC9Y658K6MA", "id"=>"55", "controller"=>"products", "action"=>"confirm_payment"}

get :confirm_payment, confirm_action_params(@product, product_purchased, paypal_token)
```

Configuration for PAYPAL_GATEWAY

`PAYPAL_GATEWAY ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)`

I haven't found any approach to achieve this so this might help many of them...

Any better solution other than this will be most appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you would have to walk through and make a test purchase.  Plus, this would allow you to go through the experience that the buyer would from start to finish.  Is there a particular reason you are trying to skip a step or two?

Some merchants will also walk thru the flow just once, and capture the information that is sent back and then just use that same string to create a form page that they just use to post the information back to their page for testing.  That way they don't have to go thru the flow over and over, but this may or may not work depending on your set up.

Most typically go with option A and go through the flow from start to finish.

Comment: @PP_MT_Chad Thanks for the help.
But this is a functional test case that can't actually visit the paypal site and complete the step of entering credentials and move forward with rest of the procedure. Yes an integration test would be handy here, but trying a way out to test it without Selenium or Web driver.